# How to set the form:path for the model attribute inside another model

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets, jstl

I am able set an individual path name for a model, but if I try to set a path for a model inside a another model it throws me an error. I stuck with this kindly give me a solution and also it would be very generous if u elaborate and explain me on what I am going worng and where is the best place learn more about this.

I would like to share my code to get it solved

THIS IS MY CONTROLLER

```
@RequestMapping(value="contact", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String contactability(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model, @ModelAttribute("contactDetails") ContactDetails contactDetails){
    try{
        if(contactDetails==null){
            contactDetails= new ContactDetails();
        }
        model.addAttribute("contactabality", contactDetails);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "contactabality";

}
```

THIS ARE MY MODELS

I have two models involed

1. contact details here's the code

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name="TB_CONTACT_DETAILS")
   public class ContactDetails implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name="CONTACT_ID")
   private Long contactId;

   @Column(name="IS_PERM_COMM_SAME")
   private Integer isPermCommSame;

   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="contactDetails")
   private Set<AddressDetails> addressDetails = new HashSet<AddressDetails>();

   public ContactDetails() {
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

   public Long getContactId() {
       return contactId;
   }

   public void setContactId(Long contactId) {
       this.contactId = contactId;
   }

   public Integer getIsPermCommSame() {
       return isPermCommSame;
   }

   public void setIsPermCommSame(Integer isPermCommSame) {
       this.isPermCommSame = isPermCommSame;
   }

   public Set<AddressDetails> getAddressDetails() {
       return addressDetails;
   }

   public void setAddressDetails(Set<AddressDetails> addressDetails) {
       this.addressDetails = addressDetails;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Is the Address Model, here's the code for it

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name="TB_ADDRESS_DETAILS")
   public class AddressDetails implements Serializable{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")
   private Long addrId;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
   @JoinColumn(name="ADDR_TYPE")
   private AddressTypeMaster addressType;

   @Column(name="ADDRESS_COL1")
   private String addrCol1;

   @Column(name="ADDRESS_COL2")
   private String addrCol2;

   @Column(name="ADDRESS_COL3")
   private String addrCol3;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
   @JoinColumn(name="CITY")
   private CityMaster city;

   @Column(name="PINCODE")
   private String pincode;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
   @JoinColumn(name="STATE")
   private StateMaster state ;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name="CONTACT_ID")
   private ContactDetails contactDetails;

   @Column(name="ADDR_STATUS")
   private String addrStatus;

   @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="addressDetails")
   private EmployeeDetails employeeDetails;

   public AddressDetails() {
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

   public Long getAddrId() {
       return addrId;
   }

   public void setAddrId(Long addrId) {
       this.addrId = addrId;
   }

   public AddressTypeMaster getAddressType() {
       return addressType;
   }

   public void setAddressType(AddressTypeMaster addressType) {
       this.addressType = addressType;
   }


   public String getAddrCol1() {
       return addrCol1;
   }

   public void setAddrCol1(String addrCol1) {
       this.addrCol1 = addrCol1;
   }

   public String getAddrCol2() {
       return addrCol2;
   }

   public void setAddrCol2(String addrCol2) {
       this.addrCol2 = addrCol2;
   }

   public String getAddrCol3() {
       return addrCol3;
   }

   public void setAddrCol3(String addrCol3) {
       this.addrCol3 = addrCol3;
   }

   public CityMaster getCity() {
       return city;
   }

   public void setCity(CityMaster city) {
       this.city = city;
   }

   public String getPincode() {
       return pincode;
   }

   public void setPincode(String pincode) {
       this.pincode = pincode;
   }

   public StateMaster getState() {
       return state;
   }

   public void setState(StateMaster state) {
       this.state = state;
   }

   public ContactDetails getContactDetails() {
       return contactDetails;
   }

   public void setContactDetails(ContactDetails contactDetails) {
       this.contactDetails = contactDetails;
   }

   public String getAddrStatus() {
       return addrStatus;
   }

   public void setAddrStatus(String addrStatus) {
       this.addrStatus = addrStatus;
   }

   public EmployeeDetails getEmployeeDetails() {
       return employeeDetails;
   }

   public void setEmployeeDetails(EmployeeDetails employeeDetails) {
       this.employeeDetails = employeeDetails;
   }
   ```

   }

THIS IS MY JSP

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Generic Tool For Employee</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/css/validator/screen.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/css/index.css">

  <div class="container-fluid">
        <h2>Contact Details</h2>
        <form:form commandName="contactabality" class="form-horizontal" id="contactDetailsForm" role="form" method="POST" action="persDetails">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">Address Details</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!--COMMUNICATION ADDRESS DETAILS-->
                     <h3 class="page-header">COMMUNICATION ADDRESS DETAILS</h3>
                         <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Address 1<span class="mandatoryRed">*</span></label>
                             <div class="col-sm-8">
                                 <form:input path="addressDetails.addrCol1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address 1" name="commAddr1" id="commAddr1"/>
                             </div>
                         </div>
         <%--                 <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Address 2</label>
                             <div class="col-sm-8">
                                 <form:input path="addressDetails.addrCol2" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address 2" name="commAddr2" id="commAddr2"/>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Address 3</label>
                             <div class="col-sm-8">
                                 <form:input path="addressDetails.addrCol3" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address 3" name="commAddr3" id="commAddr3"/>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">City<span class="mandatoryRed">*</span></label>
                             <div class="col-sm-8">
                                 <form:select path="addressDetails.city.cityId" class="form-control" name="commAddrCity" id="commAddrCity">
                                    <form:options items="${cities}"/>
                                 </form:select>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">State<span class="mandatoryRed">*</span></label>
                             <div class="col-sm-8">
                                 <form:select path="addressDetails.state.stateId" class="form-control" name="commAddrState" id="commAddrState">
                                    <form:options items="${states}" />
                                 </form:select>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Pincode<span class="mandatoryRed">*</span></label>
                             <div class="col-sm-8">
                                 <form:input path="addressDetails.pincode" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pincode" name="commAddrPincode" id="commAddrPincode" maxlength="6"/>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <!--PERMANENT ADDRESS DETAILS-->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h4 class="page-header">PERMANENT ADDRESS DETAILS</h4>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-9">Is your permanent address same as communication address<span class="mandatoryRed">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <div class="toggle-switch toggle-switch-success">
                                    <label>
                                        <form:checkbox path="isPermCommSame" id="PermAddrCheck" type="checkbox" value="2"/>
                                        <div class="toggle-switch-inner"></div>
                                        <div class="toggle-switch-switch"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row permAddrClss">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Address 1<span class="mandatoryRed">*</span></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <form:input path="addressDetails.addrCol1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address 1" name="PermAddr1" id="PermAddr1"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Address 2</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <form:input  path="addressDetails.addrCol2" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address 2" name="PermAddr2" id="PermAddr2"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Address 3</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <form:input path="addressDetails.addrCol3" type="text" path="addressDetails.addrCol3" class="form-control" placeholder="Address 3" name="PermAddr3" id="PermAddr3"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">City<span class="mandatoryRed">*</span></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <form:select path="addressDetails.city.cityId" class="form-control" name="PermAddrCity" id="PermAddrCity">
                                        <form:options items="${cities}"  />
                                    </form:select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">State<span class="mandatoryRed">*</span></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <form:select path="addressDetails.state.stateId" class="form-control" name="PermAddrState" id="PermAddrState">
                                        <form:options items="${states}"/>
                                    </form:select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Pincode<span class="mandatoryRed">*</span></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <form:input path="addressDetails.pincode" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pincode" name="PermAddrPincode" id="PermAddrPincode" maxlength="6"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>--%>
            <p>
                <input class="submit btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </p>
        </form:form> 
    </div>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="layout/js/vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="layout/js/vendors/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="layout/js/vendors/bootstrap-3.3.5.js"></script>
    <script src="layout/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="layout/js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="layout/js/contactabality.js"></script>
```

THE ERROR I GOT IS

> 4:46:34,916 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/eob-web].[jsp]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-5) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'addressDetails.addrCol1' of bean class [com.rectrix.eob.models.ContactDetails]: Bean property 'addressDetails.addrCol1' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type

AND

> 14:46:34,922 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/eob-web].[jsp]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-5) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/views/jsp/contactabality.jsp'.

Kindly help me to figure this out.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private Set<AddressDetails> addressDetails = new HashSet<AddressDetails>();
```

is your problem. I believe you are going to store only two kind of addresses in the above list, i would suggest you to bind **Permanent** and **Communication** address details as separate properties instead of binding as list.

some thing like creating two more `Transient` properties in `ContactDetails` bean `@Transient private AddressDetails commAddressDetails` and `@Transient private AddressDetails permAddressDetails` and corresponding setter/getter.

use these properties in your Jsp for respective fields, prior to persist write your own logic to construct `one-to-many` relationship. This will work if you have static number of Addresses.

Comment: I appreciate your time for helping me, thank you for that . And my other models also developed in the same fashion, like for example. I have employeeExp model which consist of pastExp attribute in which i have company name. So the name the user is trying to set from employee exp should go inside the pastExp's company name. For that In the jsp of employeeExp I gave a path for the company name as pastExp.companyName. In this case I need it to go this way but I get the same error as shown above. How to resolve this.

Comment: How is your view design in that case? -- This answer may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015654/how-to-bind-data-to-list-in-spring-form/33148339#33148339

Comment: Thank you -Lovababu. I think thats what I am trying to do. I need to bind my model with in an model. For that I used to give pastExp.companyName as a path.  But i am getting the same error

Comment: Is that also a list<PastExp> in employeeExp? If yes, you can't bind if you have dynamic size of list, so i would suggest you todo as detailed in aforementioned link.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much